# Configuration file for shell script?

Tags: zsh, vim, configuration

Is it possible to define a configuration file for zsh scripts?

I am running macOS 10.15 and the default shell is zsh.
I have defined, i.e., `alias abc="echo yes"` in ~/.zshrc, ~/.zsh_profile, ~/.profile, and ~/.zsh_login, every configuration file I can think of. However, a shell script t.sh calling `abc` will complain `command not found: abc`:

```
⇒  cat t.sh
abc
⇒  zsh t.sh
t.sh:1: command not found: abc
⇒  sh t.sh
t.sh: line 1: abc: command not found
```

I understand that adding a line `source ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.zsh_login` on the top of t.sh will work, but I wonder **is it possible to set a configuration file that runs by default for any zsh script executed on my machine (by me)?**

I'm asking this because I want to set an alias that works when I envoke a command inside vim via `:!`, e.g. `:!abc`, as well as the `]` command in the program [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn). Also please let me know if this is irrelevant to what I asked above. I'm confused of the login shell and non-login shell, or other types of shell. FYI, in vim, `:!echo $0` will return `/bin/zsh` and `:!whoami` will return `***(my name)`, so it seems like it's a login shell.

Comment: Welcome! You want a specific file to be sourced or commands available without specifying the source?

Comment: After googling about login and non-login shell, I understand that I'm talking about non-login shell, as `echo $0` returns `/bin/zsh`, without a `-` in front. But, since .zshrc is sourced by a non-login shell, why is it not working? Or, is .zshrc only for interactive shell? What about non-interactive non-login shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any zsh script you run, `~/.zshenv` will be sourced:

```
=> cat ~/.zshenv
alias abc="echo yes"
=> cat t.sh
abc
=> zsh t.sh
yes
```

A simplified hierarchy of dotfiles for zsh:

- `~/.zshenv` - sourced for all zsh scripts.
- `~/.zshrc` - sourced for all interactive zsh sessions (those attached to a
  terminal). This is usually the best place to put aliases.
- `~/.zprofile` - sourced for a login zsh session, i.e. the first interactive
  session in a set.

For your usage, it may be preferable to configure MacVim to launch an interactive
shell so it'll pick up aliases from `~/.zshrc`.  To do that, add this to your
`~/.gvimrc` (note the g) file:

```
let &shell='/bin/zsh -i'
```

For other vim flavors, you may have to do something a bit more complicated - see the answers here:
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16186/how-to-run-zsh-aliased-command-from-vim-command-mode

Comment: Thanks! Putting alias in `~/.zshenv` works both in vim (via `:!command`) and nnn (`]` then command). That's all I need.